# System.Data.SqlClient packagereference does not flow between project references

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.data.sqlclient

I can't get System.Data.SqlClient to flow over my project references even though one of the projects is dependent of it.

SqlClientDependent project .csproj:[image]

ProjectReference to SqlClientDependent project:[image]

When i build SqlClientDependent project the bin folder gets:[image]

But when i build the Project that references SqlClientDependent project, the System.Data.SqlClient is not included in bin folder, and i, ofcourse, get a runtime error beacuse the SqlClientDependent project clearly needs the SqlClient package.
Anyone understand why?

Comment: What kinds of projects are these - "old style" or SDK-style? I'd normally just use a `<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="..." />` instead of the `<Reference ...>`. That should work transitively, I believe.

Comment: SqlClient dependent projekt is "old style" (.net framework 4.6.1) and project referencing it is a new SDK-style project (.net 5.0). I think i'll remove my dependecy to System.Data.SqlClient from legacy project and try to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. But still cant figure out why it would skip the dependency....

Comment: I believe it's just a matter of dependencies not being transitive by design in old style projects. Basically it's an old problem :(